# Socket Programming Python While and If issues

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to write a hangman game using python using a simple client and server. I have the server opening and listening on the socket and then I have the client connecting to the server and sending a message and the server responding with a secret word represented by _ * by the letter count of the secret word.

I have written a hangman game that doesn't use sockets so I have that but the issue is I cannot get the If statements to work. They either return nothing or they bring up syntax errors. 
Here is the server without the if statement

```
import socket
import random

#Characters and places from HHGTTG to make it a little more difficult

word_list = [ 'agrajag','altairians','android','apple','arthur','beeblebrox',
              'betelgeuse','colin','dent','dentrassis','dolphins','eddie','fenchurch',
              'ford','galaxy','gargravarr','garkbit','god','golgafrinchans','guide',
              'hactar','harmless','hello','hitchhikers','hooloovoo','hyperspace',
              'krikkiters','lallafa','laminate','lamuella','magrathea','marvin',
              'panic','paranoid','prefect','random','roosta','russell',
              'slartibartfast','sorcerer','thor','towel','trillian','vogon','willow',
              'zaphod','zarniwoop','zarquon','zem']

lowercase = ['q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p','l','k','j','h','g','f',
             'd','s','a','z','x','c','v','b','n','m']

secret_word = random.choice(word_list)

guesses=0
letters_guessed = []
word = []


#while testing i used this a lot and i have left it in in case you want to cheat as well
#print(secret_word)

for x in range(len(secret_word)):
    word.append('_ ')

arthur = ("\n %s"%''.join(word))

def Main():
    host = ''
    port = 4242

    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((host,port))

    s.listen(1)
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print("Connection from: " + str(addr), secret_word)
    while True:
        data = c.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        if not data:
            break
        print("from connected user: " + data)
        data = data.upper()
        print("sending: " + arthur)
        c.send(arthur.encode('utf-8'))
    c.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

The if statement causing so much headache is this

```
while True:
        data = c.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        if len(data) == 1:
            print ("BlaBlaBla")
        else:
            print ("Bohoohooho")
```

Obviously that isn't the actually if and else statements i will be using in the game but it is my test and it isn't working. It keeps coming up with syntax errors which i check and then it

Comment: There's nothing wrong sytanctically in your second piece of code. Are you sure it's the code in whole here??

Comment: Thanks I just sorted it, nothing wrong with the syntax at all. It was the prog I was using to edit the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using gedit and had the setting wrong so it was adding tabs and not spaces so although it looked right it didn't work. Just changed it to adding spaces and it worked, not sure if this is supposed to happen and not even sure it is what went on but never the less I got it working.

Thanks